# Clearing cells in a table in excel when one cell is cleared

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have a table from A12 to AO29. The table headers are in row13.

I am working on a macro that deletes data in column D, E and I when the cell in column B is changed or deleted. The code below works fine, except that it is not deleting the data column D. Column D has a data validation list.

> ```
> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
> Application.EnableEvents = True
> If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H6")) Is Nothing Then
>     Application.EnableEvents = False
>     Range("H8") = vbNullString
>     Range("H7") = vbNullString
>     Application.EnableEvents = True
> End If
> If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$H6")) Is Nothing Then
>     Range("A12:B29").ClearContents
>     Range("D12:E29").ClearContents
>     Range("I12:I29").ClearContents
>     Range("A33:F50").ClearContents
>     Range("J33:J50").ClearContents
>     Range("A54:H71").ClearContents
>     Range("L54:L71").ClearContents
>     Range("A75:H92").ClearContents
>     Range("L75:L92").ClearContents
>     Range("A96:E113").ClearContents
>     Range("I96:I113").ClearContents
>     Range("A117:B134").ClearContents
>     Range("F117:F134").ClearContents
>     Range("A138:C156").ClearContents
>     Range("G138:G159").ClearContents
>     Range("A160:C177").ClearContents
>     Range("G160:G177").ClearContents
>     Range("A181:C198").ClearContents
>     Range("G181:G198").ClearContents
>     End If
>  If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
> ```

```
 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A12:A29")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Column = 1 Then Target.Offset(0, 1).clearcontent
    Target.EntireRow.Range("B1,D1,E1,I1").ClearContents

    Application.EnableEvents = True
 End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B12:B29")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Column = 1 Then Target.Offset(0, 1).clearcontent
    Target.EntireRow.Range("D1,E1,I1").ClearContents
 End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D12:D29")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Column = 1 Then Target.Offset(0, 1).clearcontent
    Target.EntireRow.Range("E1,I1").ClearContents
 End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E12:E29")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo haveError
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Column = 1 Then Target.Offset(0, 1).clearcontent
    Target.EntireRow.Range("I1").ClearContents

    Application.EnableEvents = True
 End If
 Exit Sub

 haveError:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier to manage:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, _
           Me.Range("A12:B29,D12:D29,E12:E29")) Is Nothing Then

        On Error GoTo haveError
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For Each c in Target.EntireRow.Range("B1,D1,E1,I1").Cells
            If c.Column > Target.Column Then c.ClearContents
        Next c

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    Exit Sub

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note when using `Range()` in the context of `EntireRow`, the range is *relative* to the single row.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your suggestion. I have implemented your code. I had to put it within the code that I already have for other data on the same sheet. It looks like I stuffed up your code while doing so. Could you please check my new code that I have put in the question? Maybe you can pinpoint the error and guide me to fix it.

Comment: I have just pasted it now.

Comment: See my update above - this will clear any cell in B,D,E,I on the same row and to the right of the changed cell

Comment: Perfect Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

When you're checking the b12-b29 range, you're not unionizing your ranges so the call to clear contents only affects the last range you set it to which would be the i column.

You could also condense this down drastically by replacing it with one line like this

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b12", "b29")) Is Nothing Then
    Set rngDB = Union(Range("d" & Target.Row), Range("e" & Target.Row), Range("i" & Target.Row))
    rngDB.ClearContents
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for ur formula. If I am to use my formula, how do I go abt unionizing my ranges?

Comment: If you look at Tim's answer, you don't even need to unionize an array. His code is much more concise and should serve the purpose you are after.

Comment: The truth is the code I have provided is just part of a bigger code.
What I want to do is: when A is cleared/changed, clear B,D,E & I. 
When B is cleared/changed, clear D, E & I. 
When E is cleared/changed, clear I. 
Of course this is all relative to the row cleared. 
Then I have to go write a code for the next table that changes with different columns to clear

Comment: Again, you do not need to unionize an array, you could just use the line from @Tim's answer `Target.EntireRow.Range("D1,E1,I1").ClearContents` you can just change what the column letters are on a case by case basis. The above would work for the b column for the d column it would just be `Target.EntireRow.Range("E1,I1").ClearContents`

Comment: I used his code. But it is not doing the job. Maybe I condensed it the wrong way into my other codes.